# Javascript onClick double click

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I am developing this solution for Google Earth. I have a header that has buttons created with CSS that when clicked trigger the loading of a KML. The problem I have is if the user clicks the button again it loads the same KML again. I need to prevent this from happening. I was considering once clicked it will gray out the button until the Remove KML function is selected or if the user clicks the button again it removes it. I need it to be buttons and not a checkmark.

```
function createNetworkLink(newlink) {
var networkLink = ge.createNetworkLink("");
var link = ge.createLink("");
link.setHref(newlink);
networkLink.setLink(link);
ge.getFeatures().appendChild(networkLink);
```

---

```
function LoadKML() {
var newlink = "http://www.something.com/test.kml";
createNetworkLink(newlink);
```

---

```
<div id='topmenu'>
<ul style="width: auto">
<li class='active'><a href="www.something.com"><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a title="KML 1" href='#'onClick=LoadKML();><span>KML 1</span></a></li>
<li class='last' style="width: auto"><a href='#'onClick=killKML();><span>Remove KMLs</spam></a></li>
```

I have the function working to kill the KML without issues.

---

```
function killKML(source) {
var features = ge.features().getChildNodes();
for (var i=0; i < features.getLength(); i++)
{
var feature = features.item(i);
if (! source) {
ge.getFeatures().removeChild(feature);
}
}
}
```

Comment: I think this question has nothing to do with Google App Engine.. so this tag can be ditched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no jQuery used in the code... so I'm suggesting a simple flag based solution

```
var kmlLoaded = false;

function LoadKML() {
    if (kmlLoaded) {
        return
    }
    var newlink = "http://www.something.com/test.kml";
    createNetworkLink(newlink);
    kmlLoaded=true;
}

function killKML(source) {
    kmlLoaded=false;
    var features = ge.features().getChildNodes();
    for (var i = 0; i < features.getLength(); i++) {
        var feature = features.item(i);
        if (!source) {
            ge.getFeatures().removeChild(feature);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It does prevent the double loading of the KML however when I select the clear all KML button (killKML) I am unable to select the LoadKML again.

Comment: @user2704746 did you add `kmlLoaded=false;` to the kill method

Comment: @user2704746 can you add `alert(kmlLoaded)` before the `if` condition in the load method

Comment: it fires off the alert false, when I select it again it returns true

Comment: @user2704746 after calling kill what is alerted

Comment: LoadKML
first click = False
second click = True
thrid click = True

I selected the killKML it removes it then I click on the loadKML it says true

Comment: I'm asking after clicking the clear button and again if you click load then what is alerted

Comment: that is bad because that means the `killKML`  code I gave is not getting executed... can you add a alert statement in that method and see whether it is getting called

Comment: method I'm not much of a javascript person. What method the killKML(source) ?

Comment: @user2704746 yes where you added the `kmlLoaded=false;`

Comment: @user2704746 also I hope you added the `kmlLoaded=false;` already existing `killKML` method as I updated above

Comment: That updated code worked perfectly thank you. When I click the killKML it clears it and when I select the LoadKML it returns false and loads it. Thank you again for your help it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I hate to ask this since you already helped me. When I want to add another kml I select a different LoadKML2. I have to click killKML before LoadKML2. Can I combine the killKML into a If Then Else statement for the LoadKMLs that I have?